# Will Allah Forgive my broken fasts and Skipped Salah

Tags: salat, ramadan, forgiveness, masturbation

Even though i was raised a muslim, i quickly strayed away from islam at the age of 12, since then i only pretended to be a muslim, i broke my fasts when no one was looking and only pretended to pray salat.

I also got caught up in the habit of masturbation, since last year i have realized how strayed i was and i have started to pray regularly, even though sometimes i forget or skip i try to make them up asap, due to my habit of masturbation, even this year i have broken many fasts, it is not like it used to be and i am starting to lose this habit but even as i am writing i have broken my fast through masturbation

Will Allah Forgive me for this if i never masturbate again? Because I can't possibly keep 60 fasts for each fast i missed cuz according to my calculations it will be at least a 1000 fasts, as well as will Allah Forgive my skipped namaz? Or do i have to make up both of them?